# How would you write this equation in MATLAB? (Mutual information)

Tags: matlab

I would like to put this equation into the MATLAB to calculate the global maximum of mutual information function. In order to do that, I notice that I need a gradient of the function which is described in

http://www.princeton.edu/~wbialek/rome/refs/sharpee+al_04.pdf

of equation (3.1) ( and of course we need to consider equation 3.2 too)

I do have the vector for P(x) and P(x|spike). Let's say they are called A and B respectively. Then, how do I write this down in MATLAB to calculate the gradient?

FYI, A and B are 1-by-100 vectors.

Comment: `You must be logged in to view this page!` Nice try.

Comment: Thank you jdo, I did not know that that link needs authentication.